Neutral number in XGBoost algorithm prediction
Does a concept of "neutral number" in machine learning algorithms exist?
To make it clearer: suppose we have a logistic regression with only one feature, the "neutral number" is the value of the feature that gives as output a prediction probability equal to the ratio of observations with target 1 to the total observations in the dataset.
The question is: is it possible to define a "neutral number" for a decisional tree, with multiple features? What about for a predictive model based on XGBoost?
My ultimate goal is to use a model trained on N features, M of which (with M < N of course) are not known at an "early stage" of my prediction process (so they’re not missing, they're only "unknown").
One last clarification (or constraint): I don't need a "new" model trained on the original dataset excluding the M unknown features, I'd like to take advantage of the already trained model (since I need my "early-stage prediction" to be the much closer to the "final prediction").
Thank you in advance for your help

The neutral number is just the average in this case, which requires no features.

If in a decision tree, for each feature I calculate its mean value, will I get as a result of the prediction the ratio of observations with target 1 to the total number of observations in the data set?

No, the "neutral number" is obtained without any features (with a constant to be precise), it is simply the average of the outcome variable. So for ex. if you have 3 ones and 7 zeros then the average/ratio is 0.3, and this is what you will get out of your model.  If you start including features in your model and giving them some values there is no telling what you will get, possibly nothing possibly trash.
